# Error converting a vector of gsl::byte to a gsl::span of byte

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, byte, gsl

I am working on the following piece of code, where I am trying to pass a `vector` of `gsl::byte` as a `span` of `gsl::byte` to the function `test_func`.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <gsl/span>


template <typename T, std::size_t Extent = gsl::dynamic_extent>
using span = gsl::span<T, Extent>;

using byte = gsl::byte;

void test_func(span<byte> arg)
{
  // Some tasks here
}

int main()
{
   test_func(std::vector<byte>{byte(0)});

   return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately I am getting the following error during compilation:

```
error: could not convert 'std::vector<std::byte>(std::initializer_list<std::byte>{((const std::byte*)(& const std::byte [1]{(std::byte)0})), 1}, std::allocator<std::byte>())' from 'std::vector<std::byte>' to 'span<std::byte>' {aka 'gsl::span<std::byte, 18446744073709551615>'}
```

Any suggestion on this? I thought there is an automatic conversion from vector to span but it seems not the actual scenario.
Thanks a million in advance.

Comment: Not sure if it is the same for `gsl::span` but the range constructor for `std::span` has `explicit(extent != std::dynamic_extent)` as a requirement.

Comment: Unofficially speaking `std::span` models an lvalue reference on a contiguous range. That means it cannot bind to none-const rvalues. If `span<const byte>` is used instead, then the rvalue vector can bind to const lvalue reference. I guess `gsl::span` follows similar rules.

Comment: Did you try `std::vector<byte> vec{byte(0)};  test_func(vec);`?  Ie, make the vector an lvalue.  Because as @red.wave mentioned, mutable pointers into a temporary are reasonably ruled out as a good plan unless you force it.